# How can I move a library inside a project's source tree and compiling static binaries?

Tags: c++, c, libraries, static-linking

How can I move a library inside a project's source tree and compiling static binaries?

I want to use a particular tool that utilizes ANCIENT binaries without upgrading it's API usage. This way I can use the old libraries inside the single binary without wrecking the local host environment. I am on nix with netbeans/eclipse/code::blocks.

I don't have a problem reading, just looking for a starting point. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a script to compile the lib and modify your project file to use that library's path.
for qmake it would be :

```
DEPENDPATH += . oldlib/
INCLUDEPATH += . oldlib/
LIBS += -Wl,-rpath=oldlib-build-path-L. -L../ -Loldlib-build-path -loldlib
```

Note that the rpath part is strictly for gcc, could be different on different compilers.

Comment: i primarily use gcc and am looking into using this solution...if it works i'll give the check